# Avoiding code repetition when creating multiple bundles with Gulp and Browserify

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

Given these dependencies:

```
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var maps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
```

How can I remove the code repetition in these two tasks:

```
gulp.watch('source/js/site/*.js', ['build-site-js']);
gulp.watch('source/js/admin/*.js', ['build-admin-js']);

gulp.task('build-site-js', function () {
    return gulp.src('source/js/site/site-client.js') // DIFFERENT
        .pipe(browserify({ debug: true }))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(rename('bundle.js')) // DIFFERENT
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
        .pipe(maps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(maps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('build-admin-js', function () {
    return gulp.src('source/js/admin/admin-client.js') // DIFFERENT
        .pipe(browserify({ debug: true }))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(rename('admin.js')) // DIFFERENT
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
        .pipe(maps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(maps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Notice that I’m generating two Browserify bundles using an *identical* process. The only differences between these two tasks are the names for the source and destination files. (I’ve marked the differences with `// DIFFERENT` comments.)

Ideally, I’d like to have a single `gulp.watch('source/js/**/*.js', ['build-js']);`, and then inside the task callback, determine in which directory the change occurred, and set the source and destination file names dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a function that takes the different args:

```
function doGulp(src, res) {
   return gulp.src(src) 
    .pipe(browserify({ debug: true }))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(rename(res)) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
    .pipe(maps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(maps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
    .pipe(livereload());
}
```

and call it in the tasks:

```
gulp.task('build-admin-js', function () {
  return doGulp('source/js/admin/admin-client.js','admin.js');
});
gulp.task('build-site-js', function () {
   return doGulp('source/js/site/site-client.js','bundle.js');
});
```

So that your gulpfile becomes:

```
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var maps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

function doGulp(src, res) {
   return gulp.src(src) 
    .pipe(browserify({ debug: true }))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(rename(res)) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
    .pipe(maps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(maps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
    .pipe(livereload());
}

gulp.watch('source/js/site/*.js', ['build-site-js']);
gulp.watch('source/js/admin/*.js', ['build-admin-js']);
gulp.task('build-admin-js', function () {
  return doGulp('source/js/admin/admin-client.js','admin.js');
});
gulp.task('build-site-js', function () {
   return doGulp('source/js/site/site-client.js','bundle.js');
});
```

Comment: If the Gulp task callback function provided the source path that triggered it (similar to `e.target` in DOM callbacks), this would be so much simpler. Is there a way to get to that path?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I thought about it and tried it before but didn't find a way to get it. Writing all those gulp tasks is super annoying... But I'm on a research again since you've posted the question, it really would simplify it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the accepted answer.** (Stack Overflow doesn’t allow me to accept my own answer until tomorrow. I am *not* going to set up a reminder on my phone just for this, so in case I forget, consider this the accepted answer.)

---

This setup works for me:

```
gulp.watch('source/js/**/*.js', function (options) {
    var dir = options.path.match(/\\js\\(\w+)\\/)[1]; // Windows specific [1]

    gulp.src('source/js/' + dir + '/' + dir + '-client.js')
        .pipe(browserify({ debug: true }))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
        .pipe(maps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(maps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

// [1] Use path.sep for a portable solution: nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep
```

I’m using the object argument of the `gulp.watch` callback to determine the parent directory of the changed file - either `'site'` or `'admin'` in my case. Based on that, I dynamically generate the `gulp.src` input.

To make things simpler, I’ve also removed the renaming part, so the bundles “keep” the name of the file that is the bundle’s entry point.

Comment: Nice work! You can make this OS-agnostic by replacing instances of ``\\`` with `[\\\/]` in your RegExp, or you can drop the RegExp and split the string: `options.path.split(require('path').sep)[2]`